# PhoneGap Build, This app has a plugin dependency conflict

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am trying to use the geolocation api in phonegap. I added this line to my xml file:

```
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" version="0.2.3" />
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" version="0.3.2" />
```

When I send my app to phoneGap build I get this error:

```
This app has a plugin dependency conflict (org.apache.cordova.geolocation).
```

I cant find anything on other plugins that are dependent for the geolocation one to work.

Answer (score 0):

@Mike, I am going to assume you are missing some component in your config.xml. You can check yours against my [PUBLIC demo](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/Phonegap-GPS-Test). Otherwise I would recommend you go to the "official" forum for [phonegap build](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi).